# Set TreeViewItem checkbox state with SendMessage

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a need of changing checkbox state in TreeView (exactly 'SysTreeView32') item  owned by external application - for automation purposes. I already have TreeView handle and TreeViewItem handle. I have also found some examples how I can set checkbox state, but for some reason, it is not working (SendMessage returns 0 or crashes entire application). But to the code. What i tried already is this:

TVITEM struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal struct TVITEM
{
    public int mask;
    public IntPtr hItem;
    public int state;
    public int stateMask;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pszText;
    public int cchTextMax;
    public int iImage;
    public int iSelectedImage;
    public int cChildren;
    public IntPtr lParam;
 }
```

pinvoke for SendMessage:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, ref TVITEM lParam);
```

And my method:

```
internal static void SetTreeNodeState(int treeViewHandler, int treeViewItemHandler, bool state)
{
    TVITEM tvItem = new TVITEM();
    tvItem.mask = TVIF_STATE | TVIF_HANDLE;
    tvItem.hItem = (IntPtr)treeViewItemHandler;
    tvItem.stateMask = TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
    tvItem.state = (state ? 2 : 1) << 12;
    var result = SendMessage((IntPtr)treeViewHandler, TVM_SETITEMW, IntPtr.Zero, ref tvItem);
}
```

This is the closest approach (i think, at last i did not crash target application once). Of course i have tried to sniff messages for target tree view using Spy++. What concerns me is that Spy++ shows that LParam for SendMessage is actually "TVITEMEXW" but i can beryl find anything about that struct.

Generally i also tried same think with TVM_GETITEMW, but however i did not crash application, SendMessage always returns zero.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: There are some oddities in your code that I want to point out. You use the term "handler" for something that is a "handle". You use the type `int` for these handles, but you should be using `IntPtr`. Were you to do so then you wouldn't find yourself casting the values to `IntPtr`. Those casts are a tell tale sign that something is wrong. Using `Pack=8` has to be wrong. I guess you added that when you were in trial and error mode. It's always best to post the code before you enter that mode. You use `TVM_SETITEMW` but then `CharSet.Auto`. Should be `CharSet.Unicode`.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks for pointing this out. I managed to clear my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, thanks to David Heffernan, i figured this out. I Have created overload for SendMessage, that accepts lParam as object by ref:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, IntPtr lpBuffer, uint nSize, out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] buffer, Int32 nSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, AllocationType flAllocationType, MemoryProtection flProtect);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, int dwSize, AllocationType dwFreeType);

private static IntPtr SendMessage<T>(Process process, IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, ref T lParam)
{
    uint size = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lParam);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    IntPtr processHandle = process.Handle;

    IntPtr pPointer = VirtualAllocEx(processHandle, IntPtr.Zero, size, AllocationType.Commit | AllocationType.Reserve, MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);

    IntPtr inputPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)size);
    IntPtr outputPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)size);

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(lParam, inputPtr, false);

    WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, pPointer, inputPtr, size, out UIntPtr nNbBytesWritten);
    IntPtr resultPtr = SendMessage(hWnd, msg, wParam, pPointer);
    ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, pPointer, buffer, buffer.Length, out IntPtr nNbBytesRead);

    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, outputPtr, (int)size);
    T result = Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(outputPtr);
    lParam = result;

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(inputPtr);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(outputPtr);
    VirtualFreeEx(processHandle, pPointer, 0, AllocationType.Release);
    return resultPtr;
}
```

**Usage example**

Set checkbox state for given tree view item:

```
internal static void SetTreeNodeState(IntPtr treeViewHandle, IntPtr treeViewItemHandle, bool state)
{
    TVITEM tvItem = new TVITEM
    {
        mask = TVIF_STATE | TVIF_HANDLE,
        hItem = treeViewItemHandle,
        stateMask = TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK,
        state = (uint)(state ? 2 : 1) << 12
    };

    Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName")[0];
    IntPtr ptr = SendMessage(process, treeViewHandle, TVM_SETITEMW, 0, ref tvItem);
}
```

Get checkbox state for given tree view item:

```
internal static bool GetTreeNodeState( IntPtr treeViewHandle, IntPtr treeViewItemHandle)
{
    TVITEM tvItem = new TVITEM
    {
        mask = TVIF_STATE | TVIF_HANDLE,
        hItem = treeViewItemHandle,
        stateMask = TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK,
        state = 0
    };

    Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName")[0];
    IntPtr ptr = SendMessage(process, treeViewHandle, TVM_GETITEMW, 0, ref tvItem);
    if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        uint iState = tvItem.state >> 12;
        return iState == 2 ? true : false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

TVITEM:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct TVITEM
{
    public uint mask;
    public IntPtr hItem;
    public uint state;
    public uint stateMask;
    public IntPtr pszText;
    public int cchTextMax;
    public int iImage;
    public int iSelectedImage;
    public int cChildren;
    public IntPtr lParam;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you send this particular message, you are expected to supply the address of a struct. Because the window is owned by a different process, the address you supply is not valid. Windows processes have isolated virtual memory address space. The address you supply is valid in your process, but only in your process.

In order to get around this, and send this message, you would need to allocate the memory in the target process, using `VirtualAllocEx`. You would also need to use `WriteProcessMemory` in order to populate the struct. You'd need to take care of any possible issues with struct layout if your process and the target process had different bitness. You'd need to do the same trick with members like `pszText` which themselves are pointers.

There are many questions here already that cover the subject of cross process message marshalling. I am sure that you will be able to locate them. Likewise there are a great many tutorials to be found on the web that you will find now that you are aware of the issue.

Perhaps a bigger problem is that the other process may not respond the way you expect to being poked from the outside in this way. Don't be at all surprised if you find it very challenging to be able to write your own cross process automation. Rather than doing so, why not use UI Automation?

Comment: Thank you very much! Thanks to your tips, i managed to figure this out. I'll post my solution any minute now :)